# How do rogue access points work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, encryption, wireless-access-point

From what I understand this can be done in 2 ways:

1. Installing a physical rogue AP on the authorized network
2. Creating a rogue AP on software and bridging it with the local authorized Ethernet network.

Keep in mind that I know how to create the rogue AP, I just don't understand how it works.

My questions are:

1. First and foremost, I don't understand how this works when the real AP uses encryption, unless you know the key.  It can't work if encryption is used, can it?
2. For method 2 I don't see what the point is of bridging to the local wired network. I assume that I have to connect my device to the wired network, then create the rogue AP and then bridge it to the local network. But why? Is it so that the clients of the rogue AP can connect to other hosts on the network and not suspect anything?

I found this example on Nullbyte: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-creating-invisible-rogue-access-point-siphon-off-data-undetected-0148031/

> Now that we've created an AP, we need to connect it to oil company's
>   internal, wired network. In this way, traffic through the AP will go
>   directly onto the corporate internal network and bypass all its
>   security, including any firewall or intrusion detection system.

This part just puzzles me. How is this possible?

And again what if the real AP in encrypted? Won't the clients send the packets encrypted, or isn't there some issue with certificates or something?

Comment: since the rouge device is connected to the physical wired network, the real AP doesn't even enter into the question. people connecting to the rogue device will negotiate encryption with IT, not with the real one.

Comment: @FrankThomas So, for this to work the rogue AP would have to be directly connected to the wired network, right?

Comment: yup, thats the whole idea. imagine a building with guards and machine gun turrets fortifying the perimeter, but you just dig a tunnel from next door under them and into the basement, at which point you just go upstairs, without any additional barriers.

Comment: @FrankThomas Right, I see. What about the encryption though? Is the rogue AP always open or do I have to use the same encryption mode and same keys as the real one?

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want a backdoor for access, then you would use crypto that you had keys to, but if you are trying to lure unsuspecting employees to connect to your device so you can sniff their traffic, inject malware, etc, then you would either want no encryption (so their phones connect automatically) or you would want to masquerade as them, which is more difficult, and requires you to have comprimised some portion of their network to steal certificates and other crypto artifacts.

Comment: @FrankThomas So basically with an unencrypted rogue AP the clients not only connect automatically, but there's also no certificate verification and the client's device automatically changes its encryption mode?

Comment: The wifi you are connecting to tells you its capabilities and requirements, so there is no need to change modes per se. you are just relying on an insecure configuration on the phone, that automatically joins any open wifi. they wouldn't even notice if the device was poorly configured.

Comment: @FrankThomas No what I mean is, imagine the clients were connected to the real AP which uses, for example, WPA2. You do a deauth attack and because your rogue AP with no encryption has a stronger signal, they automatically connect to your AP. My question is, don't their devices give a warning stating that either the MAC address of the AP changed or the encryption mode changed? Is there no verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "rogue AP" can mean any AP your IT department doesn't want operating in range of your facility, for any reason. They may or may not be publishing the corporate SSID or be plugged into the corporate network. There can be lots of different things that could be called "rogue APs". Here are three broad categories that most "rogue APs" fall into:

1. Some attacker creates an **impostor AP publishing the same SSID as the corporate AP,** hoping to get corporate clients to join it so the attacker can snoop on their traffic and maybe steal credentials. Or maybe just as a kind of DoS attack. Even if the corporate SSID usually uses strong security, you might be surprised how many client devices will, by default, easily let you get onto the same SSID with lesser or no security if the AP you're trying to join will allow it. It can actually be a bit of a hassle to configure some client devices so that they insist on strong security for a given SSID and refuse to join that SSID with no encryption. This kind of rogue AP may or may not be plugged into the corporate network. So, to answer your question #1, yes, its probably easier than you realize to get clients (especially clients being operated by unwitting users) to join an SSID with no encryption, even if it had previous used encryption for that SSID.
2. Some employee (or attacker) sets up **an AP, with any SSID or security setup, plugged into the corporate wired Ethernet LAN**, for whatever reason. Sometimes employees do this because they want better Wi-Fi coverage in their office, or they don't like having to deal with 802.1X (WPA2-Enterprise) authentication, or they have some mobile device they want to put on the network, but IT policy keeps them from connecting it to the corporate SSID. And of course attackers might set this up to give them a back door into the corporate network, because corporate office LANs are usually more trusted and less well monitored than Internet connections. So in answer to your question #2, Yes, people set this up so that clients of the rogue AP can get on the office Ethernet LAN and seem just about like any other office PC and can connect to internal corporate machines and systems without being detected as intrusions.
3. Someone within your facility (building/campus) runs, say, a MiFi mobile hotspot for their own reasons. It's **neither publishing the corporate SSID nor connected to the corporate LAN**, but it ends up competing for airtime on a given channel with a nearby corporate AP. This is the least harmful, most mundane example of an AP that your IT department doesn't want to see operating within their facility, but some IT departments will still consider them rogues and try to either do electronic countermeasures against them (like sending forged 802.11 deauthenticate packets to all the clients), or try to locate them via signal strength and get them shut down, and possibly pursue corrective action against the employee.